# ElasticSearch ignores "from" when using "scroll" during search?

Tags: elasticsearch

When testing ElasticSearch, I have noticed that

```
GET /vitex.inventory/Items/_search?scroll=1m
{
    "from": 10,
    "size": 10
}
```

and

```
GET /vitex.inventory/Items/_search
{
    "from": 10,
    "size": 10
}
```

does not return the same result, as the `from` parameter is completely ignored when `scroll` is used. How is that so?

Why can't a scroll start at a specified offset?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, scroll only needs `size` and `from` is not needed.

The first scroll request will retrieve `size` documents per shard and all subsequent requests will do so as well.

No need to specify `from` which will be ignored anyway.

Comment: But... why? I get that scrolling should only require a `size`, but it is odd that the API would inherently differ when specifying an extra parameter. Why can't a scroll start at a specified row?

Comment: A scroll request is different from a normal request, even if a single parameter changes. The goal of a scroll request is to scan the whole document set, so you let ES take care of browsing the docs in the way it deems most optimal for him, i.e. by using scan/scroll you don't tell him to start where you want, you simply give up that right since all you're interested in is to get all documents in an efficient way, and `from/size` pagination is not efficient at all for scrolling.

Comment: While it is a valid answer, it doesn't really add to what is already documented (i.e. not much) and does not really answer my inquiry. Accepting this answer would only discourage anyone else from adding, commenting, or give the answer that will satisfy me. In that case, I might as well delete this as it adds nothing to SO.

Comment: Fair enough, though not sure it's good idea to delete this thread.

Comment: Your question "Why can't a scroll start at a specified offset?" doesn't really have an answer different than "because that's per design" :)